# CSS3 Animate on mouse over

Tags: css, animation

I have written an animation code like such:

```
    .bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  -moz-animation-name: bounce;
  -o-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-delay: 0s;
   animation-iteration-count: 0;
   animation-direction: alternate;
   animation-play-state: paused;
}
.bounce:hover {
    animation-play-state:running;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);opacity: 1;}
  40% {transform: translateY(-20px);}
  60% {transform: translateY(-10px);}
}
```

And assigned the class "bounce" to a button on my page. When I mouse over it, it has a nice little bounce animation, but when I mouse over it again, it wont play. What can I do to make it bounce every time I mouse over it?

Comment: Try removing `animation-iteration-count: 1;`. You're not removing the animation on hover out but are just pausing it. This means that the browser would retain information about the no. of iterations that had been completed. So, when one iteration is complete, it won't execute further.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing `animation-play-state` add the animation effect when hovering.

This is an alternative approach as the animation won't continue from where it end as it restarts the animation

```css
 .bounce {
     width:50px;
     height:50px;
     background:tomato;
     border-radius:50%;  
}
.bounce:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  -moz-animation-name: bounce;
  -o-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-delay: 0s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);opacity: 1;}
  40% {transform: translateY(-20px);}
  60% {transform: translateY(-10px);}
}
```

```html
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your css property **animation-iteration-count:** value to infinite

```
 .bounce:hover {
        animation-play-state:running;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
```

**animation-iteration-count: 1;** 
by using this line of code, when you hover the button the animation will just play once and no more.

Here is the fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/wexd3spp/5/

Comment: This is the correct one. Removing `animation-iteration-count` like I had mentioned in my comment to the question alone won't work because the default value is still 1.

Comment: I assumed that, yes...although I tend to solve my problems with JQuery for things like this

Answer (score 1):

make your `animation-iteration-count: 1;` to this `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

look like this.

```
.bounce:hover {
        animation-play-state:running;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
```